# How to calculate number of day name between 2 dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have 2 datepickers and a list of checkboxes of week days. A user can select a start date or end date and check any checkbox day. I want to count the number of 
week days between 2 days.

For example: I want to join any yoga classes then I will select start or end date and also select week day like Monday , Tuesday .

Now i want to count the number of all Mondays and Tuesdays between 2 dates

```
 date1 = Mar 01,2016 
 date2 = Apr 01,2016
```

I want to count number of day name between these date like this:

> no of sunday: 4
>   no of monday: 4
>   no of tuesday: 5 etc..

I have tried this code

```
var d           = new Date(date1);
var now         = new Date(Date.now());
var daysOfYear  = [];
count           = 0;
for (d ; d <= date1 ; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  val = $("#ch_"+d.getDay());           
  if(val.is(':checked')){
    count++;
  }
}
```

But it gives a `TypeError: d.getDay is not a function`

Comment: You need to post the code you have written so far and indicate where it isn't working.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question in the current form is not a good fit. SO is for concrete questions. If you have problems getting this to work, please add your non-working code to the question and describe as precisely as possible what does not work and how it fails.

Comment: @JohannesJander sure . i will remember

Comment: Thanks :) A little head-up: this question will probably be closed because of the issue I mentioned. Closed questions count as a strike against your account and could be one factor that could lead to an account ban (if you also have frequent down-votes). Therefore, it would be wise to edit your question to make it higher quality.

Comment: @JohannesJander hey please let me know what i do. i have not understand why this question is on hold. did i not explain it? please

Comment: Please read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page and especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because that is what lead to closure of your question: no attempt to solve the problem, no code, no sign you researched the problem on your own. Don't be too shocked, a closed question is not the end of the world, but do edit the question so it fits the rules, then there's a chance it will be opened again.

Comment: @JohannesJander thanks :-) i have modified

Comment: OK, now please also describe why your code does not work (does it produce an error or does it yield no results or wrong results?) If any of that, share the type of error or the wrong results

Comment: And please do replace that `// code` with actual code. That you can code a loop doesn't help answering at all.

Comment: @JohannesJander done

Comment: Thanks. The question is on track for re-opening, I guess in a day or two it should be no longer "on hold".

Comment: @JohannesJander Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate between dates and check the day

First convert the dates into a date object

```
date1 = convertToDateObj(date1); //assuming you already have a way to parse this string to date
date2 = convertToDateObj(date2); //assuming you already have a way to parse this string to date
```

Now iterate throught them

```
var dayCount = {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0}; //0 is sunday and 6 is saturday
for (var d = date1; d <= date2; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) 
{
    dayCount[d.getDay()]++;
}
console.log(dayCount);
```

Comment: That seems a bit tedious. Surely there are the number of whole weeks of each day plus an extra 1 for each remainder day. If any day appears *n* times then any other day will appear somewhere between n-1 and n+1.

Comment: @robg you are saying why not count the weeks first and those many days to each day of the week and then count remaining days?

Comment: @robg isn't what you are suggesting even more tedius? Don't think iterating days will be an inefficient unless difference is in tens of thousands.

Comment: By tedious I mean inefficient, slow and requiring a lot more repetition than is necessary. For small ranges it will likely not matter, but for large range is might. `(end - start) / msPerWeek | 0` is the number of weeks so there are that many of each day. Then `((end - start) % msPerWeek) / msPerDay | 0` is the remainder days, so count back from the end day and add one to each of those. The processing time should be the same regardless of the length of the range. It may be a little (but not much) more code, but be much more efficient for it.

Comment: @RobG To find out number of weeks, I will first have to calculate number of days for which I will need to iterate between dates anyways. So I am not sure how it will be more efficient. Can you answer and share how it can be done? We will compare performance afterwards :)

Comment: Just about all the code you need is in my comment, given *end* and *start* are Dates, divide the total difference by the milliseconds per week (`7*8.64e7`).

Comment: @RobG day difference can still come even if the difference is one hour, i.e. if I am checking at 11PM midnight. So, millisecond difference is not a foolproof one. Anyways please share your answer. We can then compare the two :)

Comment: The OP talks about date only, not time.