# And again about calculate the number of days between two dates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, days

Seems that solution from [How to calculate the number of days between two dates using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)
work fine exept for case :
30.4.2016 - 1.5.2016 it calculate 2 days ( in real 1 )
29.2.2016 - 1.3.2016  it calculate 3 days ( in real 1 )

May be someone already found solution for these cases ?

```
This function from link
function count_days(){ // Expecting resuls: positive when date1 > date2  ; negative  when date1 < date2  
            var $obj = "dd.mm.YYYY";
            var $obj2 = "dd.mm.YYYY";
            if($obj2.value){
                $start=$obj.value.split(".");
                var date1 = new Date($start[2],$start[1],$start[0]); // Converted date to ("YYYY,mm,dd")
                var $stop=$obj2.value.split(".");
                var date2 = new Date($stop[2],$stop[1],$stop[0]); // Converted date to ("YYYY,mm,dd")
                var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
                var diffDays = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/(oneDay);
                if(diffDays >= 0){
                    return Math.abs(diffDays)+1;
                } else {
                    return diffDays-1;
                }
            }
return false; // No date2 nothing to compare  
}
// Expecting resuls in full days (24h):  
//(5.5.2016 - 5.5.2016) =  1 day (days equal)  
//(29.2.2016 - 1.3.2016) =  1 day  
//(30.4.2016 - 1.5.2016) =  1 day  
//(4.5.2016 - 5.5.2016) =  2 days  
//(29.2.2016 - null) = False   
//(1.3.2016 - 29.2.2016) = -1 day  
//(1.5.2016 - 30.4.2016) = -1 day  
//(5.5.2016 - 4.5.2016)  = -2 day
```

Comment: and what stops you from finding a solution?

Comment: `Date(2016, 4, 30)` is not 30.4.2016. `Date(2016, 3, 30)` is. You are calculating the difference between wrong dates and getting the correct result for wrong input. There's 3 days between 29.3 and 1.4, and there's 2 days between 30.5 and 1.6.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030754/how-to-calculate-number-of-day-name-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly good working code

```
function count_days(){ 
            var $obj = "dd.mm.YYYY";
            var $obj2 = "dd.mm.YYYY";
            if($obj2.value){
                $start=$obj.value.split(".");
                var date1 = new Date($start[2],$start[1]-1,$start[0]); // Converted date to ("YYYY,mm,dd")
                var $stop=$obj2.value.split(".");
                var date2 = new Date($stop[2],$stop[1]-1,$stop[0]); // Converted date to ("YYYY,mm,dd")
                var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
                var diffDays = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/(oneDay);
                if(diffDays >= 0){
                    return Math.abs(diffDays)+1; // positive as date1 > date2    
                } else {
                    return diffDays-1;  //negative  as date1 < date2
                }
            }
return false; // No date2 nothing to compare  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note that `new Date()`'s month value starts from 0 (0 - January, 1 - February and etc...).**

```
var 
  a = new Date(2016, 01, 29), // Feb 29 2016 00:00:00
  b = new Date(2016, 02, 1); // Mar 01 2016 00:00:00

alert((+b - +a) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24); // 1 day
```

An expression (+b - +a) - returns you the difference between two dates in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 millisecond).

As result you can convert:

- milliseconds to seconds: `(+b - +a) / 1000` = **86400 seconds**
- seconds to minutes: `(+b - +a) / 1000 / 60` = **1440 minutes**
- minutes to hours: `(+b - +a) / 1000 / 60 / 60` = **24 hours**
- hours to days: `(+b - +a) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24` = **1 day**

+a and +b - give you integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 for each dates.

Read more about [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> The JavaScript date is based on a time value that is milliseconds
>   since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. A day holds 86,400,000
>   milliseconds. The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to
>   100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC.

Comment: -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000  only on x64 FreeBSD on x32 FreeBSD its begins with zero (almost saw this on FreeBSD 8.0 or 9.0 )

Comment: And Your solution solution3= (+date2 - +date1) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;  
Give me these Results :
(29.2.2016 - 1.3.2016)  solutionResult: 3  (must be 1)
(30.4.2016 - 1.5.2016)  solutionResult: 2   (must be 1)
(4.5.2016 - 5.5.2016)   solutionResult: 1   (must be 2)
(5.5.2016 - 5.5.2016)   solution3: 0

Comment: Sorry but Your code give me the same results as I already have , it does not count corectly (as I expected)

Comment: Lets check: 29.2.2016 -> 29 February 2016 -> `var  a = new Date(2016, 01, 29);`  1.3.2016 -> 1 march 2016 -> `var b = new Date(2016, 02, 1);`
**Result: (+b - +a) / 1000 / 60 / 60 -> 1 DAY**. What is incorrect??

Comment: Виталий, посмотрите внимательно на пример. Используя Ваши даты я получаю значение 1, а не 3. Откуда Вы берете эти нерпавильные данные??

Comment: Finaly I found problem, thx @Ali-Mamedov !  
My mistake was in new Date() convertion lines  
var date1 = new Date($start[2],$start[1],$start[0]); -wrong   
var date2 = new Date($stop[2],$stop[1],$stop[0]);  -wrong   
var date1 = new Date($start[2],$start[1]-1,$start[0]);- Right   
var date2 = new Date($stop[2],$stop[1]-1,$stop[0]);- Right    
P.s. Stupid question . How get new line  in messages  (tryed dubble space on end and  </br> )??

Comment: Спасибо Али, что указали на ошибку.  
Я забыл отнять у месяца 1 когда присваивал new Date().

Comment: И Вам спасибо. я поэтому выделил текст **Note that new Date()'s month value starts from 0 (0 - January, 1 - February and etc...).** :). Этот момент с отниманием единицы в месяце очень коварный. очень! Надо просто запомнить и не забывать. Рад что мой ответ оказался полезным для Вас

Answer (score 0):

This code works for every case:

```
      function fmtDate( when ) {
    function D2( val ) {
      return ( val < 10 ) ? '0' + val : '' + val;
    }
    return D2( when.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' + D2( when.getDate() ) + '/' + when.getFullYear();
  }

  function workdays( d1, d2 ) {
    var result = 0;
    var d0 = new Date();
    var negative = 1;
    if ( ( typeof( d1 ) == typeof( d2 ) ) && ( typeof( d1 ) == typeof( d0 ) ) ) {
      if ( d2 < d1 ) {  // Exchange/swap the dates
        d0 = d2;
        d2 = d1;
        d1 = d0;
        negative = -1;
      }
      for ( d = d1; d < d2; d.setDate( d.getDate() + 1 ) ) {
       dow = d.getDay();     // Day Of Week: 0 (Sun) .. 6 (Sat)
       when = fmtDate( d );  // Formatted date
        if ( ( dow >= 0 ) && ( dow <= 6 )) {

            result++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert( 'workdays() - parameter error - date objects required.' );
    }
    return result
  }
```

and if you remove "=" from this line:

```
if ( ( dow >= 0 ) && ( dow <= 6 ))
```

You can use this for working out how many workdays (excluding Sat and Sun)

Comment: The same as @ali-mamedov code Yours give me wrong daynight count

Comment: The problem wasn't in @ali-mamedov's code :) .У нас как оказалось, код был верный :)